# Are 'C:\ProgramData' and 'C:\Users\All Users' the same? Do I need both?

Tags: windows-7

I have these two directories on my hard drive, which seem to be identical, and each take up 2.4GB

```
C:\Users\All Users
C:\ProgramData
```

Why do both exist? Can I get rid of one of them?

Comment: The 2.4 GB only counts once against your total hard drive space.  It's more obvious when there's a lot more in there.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Only `C:\ProgramData` actually exists as a "real" folder. `C:\Users\All Users` is a symbolic link to `C:\ProgramData`. That is, `C:\Users\All Users` points to `C:\ProgramData`, so if you navigate to the former, you are automatically redirected to the latter. That is why they appear identical.

`C:\ProgramData` is known as the "All Users Profile" and is required for the correct operation of Windows 7. Please do not delete it, if Windows even lets you.

`C:\Users\All Users` is there for backward compatibility. Poorly-written applications do not retrieve the path of the All Users Profile correctly. They say, "Windows, give me the name of the profiles directory." Windows says, "`C:\Users`." And the program says, "Okay, I know the All Users profile is called All Users and it's inside the profiles directory, so it must be `C:\Users\All Users`."  Really, what the program should say to Windows is, "Windows, give me the path of the all users profile," to which Windows would say, "`C:\ProgramData`."

Comment: The lack of space between Program and Data is a nice touch too...

Answer (score 13):

They are the same folder. Users\All Users is a junction to \ProgramData. From [Application Compatibility: Junction Points and Backup Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756982.aspx):

```
All Users legacy folder junction requirements: 

Sym links creation location     Destination  
..\Users\All Users              ..\ProgramData
```

Users\All Users is a link to the ProgramData folder for legacy reasons.  It is a junction point (symlink in the UNIX world) and not a copy of the data. I have only the ProgramData folder on my  Windows 7 (x64) computer. My guess it is safe to delete the junction point, but not necessary. I don't recommend deleting ProgramData.

Answer (score 12):

The folder `C:\Users\All Users` is a symbolic link to `C:\ProgramData`.  They're two names for the same folder.  It is there because many older programs used hard-coded paths to access the folder which doesn't exist any more.

You can delete `C:\Users\All Users`, but you won't gain anything from it.  It consumes virtually no hard drive space.

Do **not** delete `C:\ProgramData`.