# Completely remove Windows Defender

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1511

On Windows 10 Professional, with the November update (Build 10586, Version 1511) , is there any possibility to completely remove Windows Defender ?

I don't want to just disable Windows Defender.  I want to completely uninstall from my system.

Comment: Remove or totally disable?

Comment: Disable here http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15788/how-to-uninstall-disable-and-remove-windows-defender.-also-how-turn-it-off/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn off Windows Defender permanently](http://superuser.com/questions/950744/how-to-turn-off-windows-defender-permanently)

Comment: I want to Uninstall windows Defender.

Answer (score 2):

Use the program [`install_wim_tweak.exe`](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/152688-win6x-registry-tweak/).

Open a [command prompt (cmd.exe) as admin](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-open-elevated-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) and run this command:

```
install_wim_tweak.exe /o /c Windows-Defender /r
```

This **completely removes** all Defender files.

Comment: So this removes it from the install image, not the current install of windows?

Comment: @Moab this removes it from the currently running Windows

Comment: @alex have you tried it? Does it work for you?

Answer (score -1):

Despite the mediocre offering of anti-virus that is Windows Defender, you should NOT at any time run no anti-virus - even if you think you know what you are doing. Make sure you have some kind of active anti-virus installed before performing this action.

One thing you could do, is download [HBCD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/), put that onto a USB using [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) and booting into the included Mini Windows XP. Once booted, navigate to your main Windows Drive (it is not usually C:, due to weird drive letter assignments by Mini XP) -> Program Files. Select the "Windows Defender" folder. Press "[SHIFT] + [DEL]". In other words, delete permanently. Exit out of Mini XP, and reboot back into your computer. Note that this may (and probably will) have side effects, like Windows telling you it kind find the exe, or the service isn't starting, or Windows Defender is disabled.

And Windows may even end up re-downloading it again. I do not know if the process above works forever, as I have not used it myself, however the process should work. No guarantees, follow the process at your own risk.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).