# How to install Windows Defender on slipstreamed Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, iso-image, ms-security-essentials

Some guys did an excellent job at slipstreaming an .iso file of Windows 10
See download link on MajorGeeks:
http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/windows_10_bloatware_free_edition.html
Question is, how can you "re-install" Windows Defender which was excluded from that .iso? You can't download it from Microsoft...

Posted here since someone did ask a related question here some 2 years ago.

Comment: Doesn't this question violate the T&C of the license?

Comment: "License: Freeware" What?

Comment: You mount the install.wim of the ISO in question with DISM, then use a standard Windows 10 ISO and mount that, then use the standard ISO has a source for Windows Defender and using a modified approach with [install_wim_tweak.exe](https://superuser.com/questions/1003794/completely-remove-windows-defender) you add Windows Defender back to the ISO you want to use.  **The easier solution would be to custimize the standard ISO yourself if you don't know how to modify modified install.wim in question.**

Comment: You will want to use *install_wim_tweak.exe /p* be sure you read the directions and understand what you are doing before you do it.

Comment: [Create the CABs for Defender](https://superuser.com/a/1171910/174557) from a clean install.wim. Look in Mount\Windows\servicing\Packages for the correct names of the Defender packages add them via dism /addpackages back to system

Comment: Problem is, the reason i downloaded and used this slipstreamed .iso was to have Windows 10 fit on a normal DVD. Had erased my original one only to find that the new one no longer fits on standard DVD.