# How do I turn off Windows Defender from the command line?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, administrator, windows-defender

I am searching for a command to temporarily turn off Windows Defender.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Related: *[How to turn off Windows Defender permanently](https://superuser.com/questions/950744)*

Answer (score 13):

Using PowerShell (as an administrator) in Windows 10, use the following command:

```
Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true
```

To re-enable it:

```
Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $false
```

[Source](http://wmug.co.uk/wmug/b/pwin/archive/2015/05/12/quickly-disable-windows-defender-on-windows-10-using-powershell)

Comment: Readers should note that one must be running powershell "as administrator" for that to work. 

Similarly, for the sc commands in the other answers here, one must be running the command line as admin for those to work. While Powershell's error makes that clear, at the command line, one would just get "Access is denied", which is not at all obvious.

Comment: I don't think this method work anymore for 1903...

Comment: @navossoc Confirmed, ps command is still available but does not work on 1903, hmmmm.

Comment: @Moab Yeah, the last time I used this command was in version 1803 and I'm sure it worked. The 1809 version I skipped, so I can not tell for sure if it started in 1809 or 1903.

Comment: @Moab just for the sake of completeness, the command works on 1809 too...

Comment: If "Tamper Protection" is enabled then you cannot disable it via powershell

Comment: @SalmanA How do you turn that off?

Comment: @moab https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4490103/windows-10-prevent-changes-to-security-settings-with-tamper-protection

Comment: @SalmanA Thank You!

Answer (score 12):

#### I am searching for a command to turn off Windows Defender

You can use `sc` (Service Control) to stop and start Windows Defender:

```
sc stop WinDefend
```

And:

```
sc start WinDefend
```

Example output:

```
F:\test>sc stop WinDefend

SERVICE_NAME: WinDefend
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

F:\test>sc query WinDefend

SERVICE_NAME: WinDefend
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

F:\test>sc start WinDefend

SERVICE_NAME: WinDefend
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        STATE              : 2  START_PENDING
                                (NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x7d0
        PID                : 6304
        FLAGS              :

F:\test>sc query WinDefend

SERVICE_NAME: WinDefend
        TYPE               : 20  WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, ACCEPTS_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [sc](http://ss64.com/nt/sc.html) - Service Control - Create, Start, Stop, Query or Delete any Windows SERVICE.

Comment: OpenService FAILED 5: Access Denied. (In Admin CMD)

Comment: @darkore0 Running which command? What is the output from `sc query WinDefend`?

Comment: Same here. couldn't stop it.

Comment: It could be stopped/started by the commands via PowerRun v1.3 (http://www.sordum.org/9416/).

Comment: Running as admin and still got Access is denied error.

Comment: @DavidPostill Does this still work for version 2004? I heard you can no longer disable defender?

Comment: @Moab I've absolutely no idea. I'm running Windows 7 :)

Comment: Windows 10 21H1, calls to stop WinDefend service are intercepted by Defender itself, PowerShell method also silently fails.

Answer (score 4):

To disable:

```
sc config WinDefend start= disabled
sc stop WinDefend
```

To re-enable:

```
sc config WinDefend start= auto
sc start WinDefend
```

Don't forget about the space after "start=" or the command will not work.

PS. You can get further description of these commands by typing:

```
sc /?
sc config /?
```

Answer (score 0):

Run cmd as administrator for elevated privileges,

type the command to turn off windows defender firewall

netsh advfirewall set all state off

type the command to turn on windows defender firewall

netsh advfirewall set all state on

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).