# Cannot disable windows defender

Tags: windows, windows-10, anti-virus, windows-defender

Running Windows 10 x86-64. 
I have installed Avira antivirus and want to completly diable windows defender. In the control panel's security and maintnence page, I am informed that both are turned on, so I clicked the view installed antivirus apps button, once I do that, I cannot find any menu options to disable windows defender.

Despite the control panel menu, the Windows defneder says it is disabled.
Despite that, it is showing up in the task bar.

Comment: Why not just remove the Windows Defender icon fromt the taskbarif its disabled?  You cannot remove Windows Defender.  It is also safe, on Version 1607, to have both Avira and Windows Defender instaleld and enabled.

Comment: As @Ramhound has said. You cannot remove windows defender, but you can open windows defender, go to settings in the upper right hand corner, and turn off Real-time protection and Cloud based protection. Essentially stopping windows defender from doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Defender is hard-baked into Windows 10. It cannot be removed. It can be disabled shortly in the settings (in settings -> security), but will turn itself back on after about 10 minutes or so. Same things goes for the associated services.

Expounding on what Ramhound said, it *is* safe to run both at the same time.

If you would to remove the defender icon from the notify tray, right click the task bar, go to settings, and then scroll down to notification area settings. Choose 'Select which icons appear on the taskbar' and then disable whichever icons you do not wish to see.

Comment: "but will turn itself back on after about 10 minutes or so." - Only if you turn it off the way you describe.  [How to turn off Windows Defender permanently](http://superuser.com/questions/950744/how-to-turn-off-windows-defender-permanently).

Comment: Windows says I can get a performance hit from them both running. And just last week defender fully disablediteself becuase I had avira installed. Any way I can revert to that state?