# Is it safe to remove Windows Defender?

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

I've recently been rather fed up with Windows, and have started removing useless system apps like Edge & IE, and I constantly see Windows Defender using 30+% of my CPU.

I have another antivirus. A better antivirus, so that's no issue. The only thing I'm worried about is whether or not Windows will stably work if I remove Windows Defender. I have heard news of Windows seemingly "breaking" when removing core packages.

**Is it safe to remove defender? Will Windows functionality be hindered by the removal?**

***EDIT:*** This question is not about how to remove Windows Defender.

> Why do so many users assume the question is "how to remove?", while it's "is it safe?"

Comment: While I agree this is a dup ironically it seems to suggest the asker really only **needs** to disable Windows Defender not remove it.

Comment: You can’t remove defender. So it’s moot.

Comment: I believe @David perhaps simply wants to _lower CPU usage_ caused by Defender, which can be accomplished by **disabling** the service and the functionality, not removing it *per se*

Comment: See this URI in regards to removing Win 10 Apps (**not** defender) via Powerhshell: https://www.howtogeek.com/224798/how-to-uninstall-windows-10s-built-in-apps-and-how-to-reinstall-them/

Comment: @Appleoddity Sure, you can, see Andre’s answer to the duplicate

Comment: **Why do so many users assume the question is "how to remove?", while it's "is it safe?"** David is not saying he doesn't know how to remove Windows Defender, but "the only thing I'm worried about is whether or not Windows will stably work if I remove Windows Defender".  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Defender has had a history of not playing perfectly nicely with other antivirus installed - they can start arguing over who should scan a file, or if one scans it the other notices and triggers the on access scanner - back and forth for a while wasting resources. To be fair, installing any two virus scanners at the same time with real time or on access scanning will likely give this behaviour. Full system scans could also use a lot of CPU and disk activity (which is why I recommend using only on access scanning).

I've not seen any descriptions of *removing* Windows Defender entirely. If there are certain files that could be deleted, I don't know them.

When you install another antivirus, Windows Defender should automatically be disabled:

> Starting with the Windows 10 Anniversary Update in the Summer of 2016,
>   Windows Defender can actually run alongside another antivirus app.
>   When you install another app, Windows Defender itself isn’t
>   disabled—just its real-time protection component is. That means your
>   third-party app handles real-time protection, but you can still run a
>   manual scan with Defender whenever you want.
>
> https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15788/how-to-uninstall-disable-and-remove-windows-defender.-also-how-turn-it-off/

To disable on access scanning manually, [Microsoft says](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4027187/windows-turn-off-windows-defender-antivirus)

> 1. Open Windows Defender Security Center, then select Virus & threat
>      protection > Threat settings.
> 2. Turn off Real-time protection. Note:
>      Scheduled scans will continue to run. However, files that are
>      downloaded or installed will not be scanned.

If you find it re-enables itself, methods for keeping it turned off more permanently [include](https://www.maketecheasier.com/permanently-disable-windows-defender-windows-10/):

> Open Regedit and browse to
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Policies > Microsoft > Windows Defender
>
> Create or edit a key called 'DisableAntiSpyware' to have the value '1'.

Or, if you have a Pro or Enteprise edition of Windows:

> Press the “Windows key + R” to load the Run box, then type gpedit.msc
>   into the box and press OK to get the group policy editor. Then browse
>   to
>
> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates> Windows
>   Components > Windows Defender
>
> Open the “Turn off Windows Defender”
>   policy, and enable it.

Answer (score 2):

If disabling Windows Defender is sufficient, you can do this by emulating the registry entry that group policy editor uses to disable it. Run regedit and navigate to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender
```

Create a DWORD entry called "DisableAntiSpyware" and set it to 1. When you reboot, the Windows Defender service will be stopped. Indeed, after this, even trying to manually start the service will fail, so remember where you parked, so to speak, if you want to undo this later.

Answer (score 1):

This depends, are you referring to **system stability**, **malicious programs** or other points.

To remove Windows Defender, first download [win6x Registry Tweak](https://www.msfn.org/board/topic/152688-win6x_registry_tweak/) and run the following from an elevated command prompt:

```
install_wim_tweak.exe /o /c Windows-Defender /r
```

More topics:

- [How to disable Windows Defender on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15788/how-to-uninstall-disable-and-remove-windows-defender.-also-how-turn-it-off/)
- [How to turn off Windows Defender permanently](https://superuser.com/questions/950744/how-to-turn-off-windows-defender-permanently)

Comment: I won't downvote this answer, but I don't agree with it. Its never a good idea to recommend installing software for a task when it can be done with resources already available.

Comment: That is understandable. But this user may not be comfortable with registry/services etc.

Comment: Well, this is SuperUser afterall. Most people here at least dare to touch a pc more than a casual user.

Comment: @LPChip Not disagreeing with you. Just for someone "wanting to uninstall defender" as opposed to disabling it due to CPU utilization, I suspect they're not the best at PC operations ;)