# Windows 10 - Stopping Antimalware Service Executable Permanently

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

How do I stop the Malware Service Executable permanently in Windows 10 ?

I tried:

1) Using Group Policies in Windows 10 - Turned it and off and Disabled it
Status: Still Running when I search under Processes at Windows Re-Start

2) Tried Registry Editor
Status: I changed permissions, take ownership of registry keys and it wont let me change the keys

3) Tried Disabling it in Windows Security Center
Status: Still Running when I search under Processes at Windows Re-Start

4) Tried Killing it Under Processes in Windows Task Manager
Status: Says that is denied.

I want to get rid of this permanently.

What can I do ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to turn off Windows Defender permanently](https://superuser.com/questions/950744/how-to-turn-off-windows-defender-permanently)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Windows Defender in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/947873/disable-windows-defender-in-windows-10)