# How to disable (signature-based) real-time scanning and leave behavior monitoring enabled in Windows Defender?

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, group-policy, windows-defender

I believe that Windows Defender included in Windows 10 implements some forms of protection other than signature-based threat detection. Two Group Policy settings indicates this: "**Turn on behavior monitoring**" and "**Monitor file and program activity on your computer**".

Since I really dislike signature based-detection (and employ a really strict policy for threat mitigation instead), it's of my best interest to disable real-time file scanning in my Windows 10 system, but without turning off real-time protection entirely. Can it be done?

There's a policy setting called "*Turn off real-time protection*", but judging by it's name, I'm afraid it disables the other components. There's also "*Scan all downloaded files and attachments*", which I tried setting to Disabled, but doesn't seem to work (browsing through files and plugging external drives still triggers file scanning).

Thanks.

Comment: Real-time protection is behavior based; it's either enabled or not;  defender Defender doesn't employ anything else

Comment: @Ramhound Not really. Real-time protection is, without a doubt, signature-based, and -supposedly- some other mechanisms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself (more details [here](https://superuser.com/a/1090888/358758)). Basically, it's as simple as setting the Group Policy called `Monitor file and program activity on your computer` to **Disabled**.

For users of Windows editions without *gpedit.msc*, a DWORD entry called `DisableOnAccessProtection` must be created under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Real-Time Protection` and set to **1**.

The name of this registry entry tells you exactly what "Monitor file and program activity" actually do: It scans files "On Access" (such as when Windows Explorer lists the contents of a directory). Nothing more.

Comment: Can anyone verify this works for W10 version 2004?